# comparing values in a datarow VB

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, datarow

I want to compare Values in two datarows row and row1. But this code is Generating an Error

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    For Each row1 As DataRow In tmpdt.Rows
        If row["STATE"].Tostring() = row1["STATE"].Tostring() Then

        End If
    Next
Next
```

Error:

> Value of type 'System.Data.DataRow' cannot be converted to 'Boolean'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use round brackets `()` instead of `[]`

This would work:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    For Each row1 As DataRow In tmpdt.Rows
        If row("STATE").Tostring() = row1("STATE").Tostring() Then

        End If
    Next
Next
```